# NAT not working for wireless host

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I'm trying to serve a page, to the Internet, from my raspberry pi. I'm able to view the page inside my WLAN.

My router is a DI-524, I configured the virtual server, so the chosen port is opened. A similar configuration is working for another host (wired). So, I'm guessing it has something to do with wireless hosts.

Hope someone can help!

EDIT

I tested the raspberry pi cabled, connected directly to the router, and it did not work. The former is getting it's IP through DHCP (I think it makes no difference).

I also tested a laptop (wirelessly) and it worked.

ifconfig output the from raspberry pi

```
eth0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:0b:93:cf  
        inet addr:192.168.0.26  Bcast:192.168.0.31  Mask:255.255.255.224
        inet6 addr: fe80::ba27:ebff:fe0b:93cf/64 Scope:Link
        UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
        RX packets:5589 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
        TX packets:2522 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
        collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
        RX bytes:847888 (828.0 KiB)  TX bytes:281045 (274.4 KiB)

lo    Link encap:Local Loopback  
        inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
        inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
        UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
        RX packets:114 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
        TX packets:114 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
        collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
        RX bytes:63840 (62.3 KiB)  TX bytes:63840 (62.3 KiB)
```

ifconfig output from the laptop (partial)

```
en1: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
        ether 28:cf:e9:63:54:e9 
        inet6 fe80::2acf:e9ff:fe63:54e9%en1 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x5 
        inet 192.168.0.29 netmask 0xffffffe0 broadcast 192.168.0.31
        nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
        media: autoselect
        status: active</blockquote>
```

Comment: Does the raspberry pi have both ethernet and wireless interfaces in use? (is it connected twice?)

Comment: No. I'll test it via ethernet and report later. Thanks for your comment, @Geditdk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me some time to check the obvious, **iptables**. My version of raspbmc configures it to drop all connections originated outside my LAN.

To let raspbmc accept connections from outside one's LAN, one should delete the file `/etc/network/if-up.d/secure-rmc`.